# What is the meaning of the sentence below?

Tags: meaning

Would you please help me with the meaning of the last part of a sentence? What is the meaning and the connection of the part in bold with the first part?

> In fact, her parents had apparently decided that it was a wonderful idea,
>   an inspiring idea, **an idea so amazing it should have little baby ideas that
>   could run around and ruin everything.**

Comment: Was the "wonderful" idea something that the girl ("her") didn't agree with? (And was it perhaps something to do with babies, e.g., a sibling she didn't want? Just guessing here since you didn't provide context.)

Comment: dear friend, they are twins -12 years old- who are planed to be separated in school, so yes, they disagree

Answer (score 1):

As with so many ideas, one generally lead to another and another, and her parents probably started adding all kinds of ideas to whatever the first one was, and all their ideas would overwhelm and ruin the girl’s own original idea and plan. As a parent I have been criticized by my own kids for doing just that-taking their own idea and then making it “mine” (a parental risk when one wants to “help.”)
The image here with “baby ideas” seems a bit awkward, somehow.

Comment: thank you dear friend for your response. but the story is about twin girls whose parents have decided separate their classes in 5th grade. so they disagree. there is just one idea, not many. and unfortunately, again i didn't get it :(

Comment: The image of "baby ideas" seems to me to be a typical teenage sarcastic overreaching metaphor.

Comment: The idea of separating the girls at school may have lead to more ideas of separating their twin lives, in other ways too, that would ruin the girls happy lives together. Some parents might worry that twins won’t have their own identities, so they try to separate them more. Some twins might like the autonomy, but possibly in this case the twins loved being together and did not want that, if they were very close. Without reading more of the context this was written in, it would be hard to delve deeper into the meaning. Clearly this was a somewhat odd way to describe what was going on!

Comment: Other “baby ideas” could be that the parents started thinking such things as sending the twins to different dance classes, different summer camps, different activities, etc.

Comment: It's not a great metaphor, but this seems the only natural meaning: that's so great that it should or will spawn lots of offspring. This is linked into another separate, contradictory idea, that children are trouble and will ruin your life. Together they don't make a lot of sense, but nobody says every published bit of writing makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is the overreaction of the teenage mind which finds the idea most terrible and fears the change that it threatens will grow to overwhelm the teenager's world. Such reactions describe things to be exponentially worse than they are as a form of panic in the face of possible change and are as colorfully descriptive as they can get.